# Get coordinates of non-nan values of xarray Dataset

Tags: numpy, python-xarray

I have this sample Dataset containing worldwide air temperature, and more importantly, a mask `land`, marking land/non-water areas.

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 55, lon: 143, time: 5)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2016-01-01 2016-01-02 2016-01-03 ...
  * lat      (lat) float64 -52.5 -50.0 -47.5 -45.0 -42.5 -40.0 -37.5 -35.0 ...
  * lon      (lon) float64 -177.5 -175.0 -172.5 -170.0 -167.5 -165.0 -162.5 ...
    land     (lat, lon) bool False False False False False False False False ...
Data variables:
    airt     (time, lat, lon) float64 7.952 7.61 7.389 7.267 7.124 6.989 ...
```

I can now mask the oceans and plot it

```
dry_areas = ds.where(ds.land)
dry_areas.airt.plot()
```

[image: Plot land areas only]
`dry_areas` looks like this

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 55, lon: 143)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 -52.5 -50.0 -47.5 -45.0 -42.5 -40.0 -37.5 -35.0 ...
  * lon      (lon) float64 -177.5 -175.0 -172.5 -170.0 -167.5 -165.0 -162.5 ...
    land     (lat, lon) bool False False False False False False False False ...
Data variables:
    airt     (lat, lon) float64 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan ...
```

**How can I now get the coordinates for all non-nan values?**

`dry_areas.coords` gives me the bounding box and I can't get lat and lon into the `(55, 143)` shape so I could apply the mask on.

The only working workaround I could find is
`dry_areas.to_dataframe().dropna().reset_index()[['lat', 'lon']].values`, which does not feel very lean and clean.

I feel this is quite simply, however I am clearly not a numpy/matrix ninja.

**Best solution so far**

This is the shortest I could come with so far:

```
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(ds.coords['lon'], ds.coords['lat'])
lat_masked  = ma.array(lat, mask=dry_areas.airt.fillna(False))
lon_masked  = ma.array(lon, mask=dry_areas.airt.fillna(False))
land_coordinates = zip(lat_masked[lat_masked.mask].data,     lon_masked[lon_masked.mask].data)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `.stack` to get an array of coord pairs of the non-null values:

```
In [31]: da=xr.DataArray(np.arange(20).reshape(5,4))
In [33]: da_nans = da.where(da % 2 == 1)
In [34]: da_nans
Out[34]:
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 5, dim_1: 4)>
array([[ nan,   1.,  nan,   3.],
       [ nan,   5.,  nan,   7.],
       [ nan,   9.,  nan,  11.],
       [ nan,  13.,  nan,  15.],
       [ nan,  17.,  nan,  19.]])
Coordinates:
  * dim_0    (dim_0) int64 0 1 2 3 4
  * dim_1    (dim_1) int64 0 1 2 3

In [35]: da_stacked = da_nans.stack(x=['dim_0','dim_1'])

In [36]: da_stacked
Out[36]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 20)>
array([ nan,   1.,  nan,   3.,  nan,   5.,  nan,   7.,  nan,   9.,  nan,
        11.,  nan,  13.,  nan,  15.,  nan,  17.,  nan,  19.])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) object (0, 0) (0, 1) (0, 2) (0, 3) (1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2) ...


In [37]: da_stacked[da_stacked.notnull()]
Out[37]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 10)>
array([  1.,   3.,   5.,   7.,   9.,  11.,  13.,  15.,  17.,  19.])
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) object (0, 1) (0, 3) (1, 1) (1, 3) (2, 1) (2, 3) (3, 1) ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Still a bit complicated imo. Shouldn't this be a standard use case?

Comment: Tbh I think it's about as terse as it should be. But not with much confidence and PRs always welcome!

Comment: Your're right, since this actually boils down to only 2 lines: da_stacked = dry_areas.airt.stack(notnull=['lat','lon'])
da_stacked[da_stacked.notnull()]

Comment: Still, `stack` doesn't exactly scream out "report the coordinates of a value." At the very least, I think this should be added to the xarray "How do I?" documentation page. More ideally, I urge packaging this up into something that offers the affordance of finding desired values.

Comment: Hi @RobertP.Goldman! Just came back to this and saw your comment. Hope all's well. PRs welcome!

Comment: @Maximilian I have put a gist here https://gist.github.com/rpgoldman/8f0c43d151793d682575f4696512e3e8 -- it shows the use of this technique to get the coordinates, but I still don't have a great solution to *using* the coordinates once I have them in hand, because they are wrapped in a `Coordinates` object.

Comment: Great! I responded there!